# Getting Nil Value in function that I am running an RSpec test on...?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Can someone please help a newb?
I am running the following two tests trying to get the same value in the end.  However; when I run the test through the computer_turn method, it gives me a nil value, but when I run the test directly through the function of player_first_turn? it returns the value of :b2 I am looking for.  Why isn't the former giving me :b2 as well?

THE RSPEC TESTS.

```
before(:all) do
  @test_case = ComputerLogic.new
  $user_sign = "X"
  $computer_name = "Watson"
  $computer_sign = "O"
end

context "pertaining to computer_turn" do
  it "should: if player picks corner then computer picks center" do
    possible_places = {a1: "X",a2: @a2,a3: @a3,b1: @b1,b2: @b2,b3: @b3,c1: @c1,c2: @c2,c3: @c3}

    @test_case.computer_turn(possible_places).should == :b2
  end
end

context "pertaining to player_first_turn? and computer_first_move" do
  it "should: if player picks corner then computer picks center" do
    possible_places = {a1: "X",a2: @a2,a3: @a3,b1: @b1,b2: @b2,b3: @b3,c1: @c1,c2: @c2,c3: @c3}

    @test_case.player_first_turn?(possible_places).should == :b2
  end
```

THE FUNCTIONS I AM RUNNING THE RSPEC TESTS ON.

```
def computer_turn(possible_places)
  if player_first_turn?(possible_places)
  elsif attack
  elsif counter_attack
  elsif fork_play?
  else random_move
  end
end

def player_first_turn?(possible_places)
  @first_turn = possible_places.select { |key, value| value == $user_sign }
  if @first_turn.length == 1
    return computer_first_move
  else
    return false
  end
end

def computer_first_move
  check_center = @first_turn.keys.first
  if check_center == :b2
    move = { a1: @a1,a3: @a3, c1: @c1,c3: @c3 }.keys.sample
    #return declare_computer_move(move)
  else
    move = :b2
    #return declare_computer_move(move)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you confusing the function names? `computer_first_move` is what seems to return `:b2`, but both your question and test are expecting `computer_turn` to return `:b2` which isn't clear that it does.

Comment: No, both ways cascade through to computer_first_move, from the computer_turn and player_first_move?

Comment: What line in `computer_turn` are you expecting it to return `:b2`?

Comment: I think you answered my question; thank you.  I think you are saying if player_first_turn?(possible_places), return computer_first_move.

Comment: I wasn't implying that, but I'm glad the questions helped :)

Comment: The problem is that `computer_turn` returns `nil` if `player_first_turn?(possible_places)` is truthy since there is no code between the `if` expression and the following `elsif`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `computer_turn` returns `nil` if `player_first_turn?(possible_places)` is truthy since there is no code between the `if` expression and the following `elsif`. In fact, `computer_move` will return `nil` in case *any* of the conditional expressions are truthy, otherwise it will return `random_move`.

The `if` statement never returns the value of the conditionals it is evaluating. It returns the value of the statement series or expression following the conditional expression or `nil` if none if that is empty.